# Use raw string to run a sub process

Tags: python, subprocess

This is kind of weird, but I am running a program called scrapebox, scrapebox has an automator plugin that creates a file to automagically run a few things within. In order to run the automator from cmd I would cd into the program directory then type:

```
Scrapebox.exe "automator:1.sbaf"
```

It would first launch Scrapebox the program, once open, it would immediately run the automated file.

This is a small piece in a much bigger puzzle. I am trying to call that within a larger Python script.

```
import os
import subprocess
..........
..........
..........
print "Opening Scrapebox now, please wait."

os.chdir('C:\Users\Admin\DomainDB\Programs\ScrapeBox')

print
print "Current working dir : %s" % os.getcwd()
print

subprocess.call(["Scrapebox.exe"])
#"automator:1.sbaf"

print "Scrapebox finished. Moving on."
```

When I run it as above, it works and opens scrapebox. But, what I really need to do is something like this:

```
subprocess.call(["Scrapebox.exe "automator:1.sbaf""])
```

When I do that it throws a syntax error. So how can I input that maybe as a raw string as though it were being typed into cmd?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to embed double quotes in a string, you can use one of a number of ways.  Also to pass a single string of all arguments, don't pass as a list `[]`:

```
subprocess.call("Scrapebox.exe \"automator:1.sbaf\"")
subprocess.call('Scrapebox.exe "automator:1.sbaf"')
```

Python can use either single- or double-quotes around a string.  You can also triple-quote a string (three single- or double-quotes at the start and end), which allows newlines as well, but it is not needed here.

If you pass a list of arguments, each argument should be an element of the list:

```
subprocess.call(['Scrapebox.exe','automator:1.sbaf'])
```

Comment: That worked like a charm! I figured it was a matter of my use of quotes. Just couldn't get the correct combination! Thanks!

Comment: In your last example, the second argument in the list seems to be missing double quotes, nested in the single quotes.

Comment: @Eliad quotes are needed in some cases by the shell. When the parameters are already broken up into a list they are not needed.

Comment: @MarkTolonen thanks for this remark, it helped me solve a bug in my project!